# Need to get the child elements

Tags: xpath

iterate and get the values of  ProductName and ProductId for each node. what is the xpath syntax. Please help

## Here is the xml file:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ProductName>PDPArch</ProductName>
        <ProductId>57947</ProductId>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductName>TYFTType</ProductName>
        <ProductId>94384</ProductId>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, had to rearrange things a bit. YOu'll need to do something like this:

```
while (nodes.MoveNext())
{
   // here, we're on the Product node
   string productName = null;
   string productId = null;

   // does it have child nodes?    
   if (nodes.Current.HasChildren)
   {
      // go to the first child node
      bool hasMore = nodes.Current.MoveToFirstChild();

      while (hasMore)
      {
         // extract the info
         if (nodes.Current.Name == "ProductName")
         {
             productName = nodes.Current.Value;
         }

         if (nodes.Current.Name == "ProductId")
         {
            productId = nodes.Current.Value;
         }

         // does it have more children?
         hasMore = nodes.Current.MoveToNext();
      }
   }
}
```

Marc

**UPDATE:**
An easier way to do this might be this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("Your XML file name.xml");

XmlNodeList list = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Products/Product");

foreach(XmlNode node in list)
{
  string productName = node.SelectSingleNode("ProductName").InnerText;
  int productID = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("ProductId").InnerText);
}
```

No messy XPathIterator and navigator and everything...... this works in .NET 1.x and 2.x and up.

In .NET 3.5 and up, you could also use Linq-to-XML to parse the XML more easily.

Comment: What its doing is getting the ProductName from the next node instead of ProductId from the current node?

Comment: @marc_s: This leaves me puzzled - why did you implement a complicated iteration when `SelectNodes()` and some trivial XPath would have been enough?

Comment: @Tomalak: because the OP had this (sort of) in his original question, and I didn't want to totally change everything.

Comment: In the meantime, I've found the original question. :-)

Comment: okay. I am a newbie and hence the complicated way. Is there a optimized way of achieving this result